# How do I save an image from twitter.com on a browser?

Tags: twitter

Twitter apparently doesn't like the idea of people saving images and other  media elements from their feed, because they've made it awfully difficult. Things I've tried

- right click hoping for save option  (nope)
- left click hoping for expanded image (nothing happens)
- inspect element using browser debugger (no obvious img element)
- search for chrome extension (none that worked for me)

Any other ideas?

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I changed the title of the question. I'm on a ordinary browser (Chrome), simply going to twitter.com. Twitter is intercepting right clicks.

Comment: Okay, then, you most likely have a rogue extension. I use Chrome and it works just fine. Try launching Chrome without any extensions. (Incognito mode should suffice.)

Answer (score 22):

Below is a trick found [here](https://nocodewebscraping.com/how-to-download-videos-and-pictures-from-twitter/) that worked for me.

1. click on the tweet (the browser will show you the tweet url in the bar)
2. insert **mobile.** in the url before **twitter.com** and navigate to the mobile version
3. click on the image in the tweet
4. right click and save the gif/mp4 or the images

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any longer. I've tried in Firefox and Chrome, and even on my iPhone.

Comment: @gevra it still works thank you so much much love from iceland <3

Comment: Inserting just an `m` also works.

Comment: this still works, verified in 2019.

Answer (score 7):

So there's a couple of things at play here. Firstly, what you're looking at on twitter is actually a video, not a gif. They convert all animated gifs to videos to save on bandwidth (generally videos are smaller than the same content as an animated gif).

A quick (possibly hacky) way of getting the content (I've used, disclosure, I wrote it), is to use Snapbird to find the tweet then download straight from there: https://snapbird.org/sheenadempsey/timeline/waiting (you'll need to auth to search, and yeah, the permissions are aggressive due to twitter's limited control over API access - if you want to read DMs you need to get write perms—!?!?).

Anyway, that should work (and of course, if you can find the video element in devtools somewhere, that works too) :)

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for joining this site just to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives with fewer mouseclicks than Gevra's answer.

Right-click on the picture in the tweet, select *open image in new tab*, append `:orig` to the url, hit F5 to reload.

Or right-click on the picture in the tweet, select *copy image url*, open new tab, paste the url, append `:orig` to it and hit enter.

`:large` instead of `:orig` also works, but `:orig` can have better results than large (thanks to [Alex Vong](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/212593/alex-vong) for pointing that out.

Comment: No, `:orig` can have better resolution than `:large`. Consider https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DtPuZuZWwAATBHt.jpg:orig vs https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DtPuZuZWwAATBHt.jpg:large

Comment: This won't work with albums in 2019.

Answer (score 1):

How to Save Twitter Pictures on Browser:

1. Open Browser.
2. Login to Twitter.com Website.
3. Find Photo that you want to save.
4. Open photo in full screen.
5. Right Click on Photo and then choose to save image as.
6. Now Select Folder where you want to Save.

Source - [HubsAdda](https://hubsadda.com/how-to-save-twitter-pictures/)

Comment: Thanks. This works nowadays (most of the time) with static GIFs, but not with animated GIFs as far as I can tell. For example, try the Peter Sellers GIF here: https://twitter.com/SheenaDempsey/status/797580955586273280.  I guess I should update my question to specify animated GIFs.

Comment: I understand It does not work in Animated GIF

Answer (score 0):

- click on tweet so that the rest of the page is grayed out but DO NOT click on the photo otherwise it will only be saved as a webpage file
- right click on the image and select 'save image as'
- once file explorer opens, head down to 'save as file' and click the drop down menu
- select 'all files'
- name the file and add '.png' or '.jpeg' directly after it
- click save

Answer (score 0):

This one just worked with me on Google:

- if you're having trouble in downloading an image from twitter on a browser, it's most likely that the image is a pfp.

  1. find the image
  2. right click the page and select "Inspect"(or just Ctrl + Shift + I)
  3. click this icon on the top left corner

[image: click this icon on the top left corner]

4. select the image
5. on elements, hover your mouse around and find the line that matches the image size and you think contains the image

[image]

6. right click it, select "Edit as HTML", and search for the image link

[image]

7. copy and paste the link on your search bar and voila! there you have your downloadable image

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution - USE INCOGNITO - then you can save any profile image in seconds.

See my 20-second screencast here https://www.screencast.com/t/5QTCy0ezm

Answer (score -1):

As a last resort, use any screen capture tool that you have installed, e.g. the windows snipping tool.
This will *always* work regardless of what any website owner tries to prevent you from downloading images.

Note that your image will not be in its original resolution, it will be the size and resolution of what you see on your screen.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the image and then there should be an option that says "search google for image". You press that then go to the images and you then have your saved image.

Answer (score -2):

hi guys i found a solution on how to download pictures from twitter using your pc and its a bit frustrating to do. first click/open your desired picture, 2nd right click it then click inspect, a window will appear on the right side of your screen and a bunch of codes will be there, if you want to download the picture you must thoroughly click all the small arrows just beside the codes until you find the link of the picture, just hover your mouse the link will be in blue color and once you hover onto it a glimpse of the picture that you want to download will appear then right click it and click open link in new tab or copy the link then paste in the search bar. i just downloaded my 1st picture from twitter